# How do I change the datatype of a field in an XSD file using bindings.xjd file(customized binding )

Tags: xml, xsd

I have following XSD schema file

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="built-ins/sws_common.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="VoidTicketRQ">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Ticketing">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="eTicketNumber" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="RPH" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ReturnHostCommand" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="TimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string" fixed="2.0.2" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I would like to add an external binding to change the datatype of the field `eTicketNumber` to `xs:string` (which is currently `xs:integer`).

I have tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="VoidTicketLLS2.0.2RQ.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">       
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Ticketing']"> 
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='eTicketNumber']"> 
      <jaxb:bindings type="xs:string"/> 
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Please give me some advice.